# Nearby Connections API encryption

Tags: android, encryption, google-nearby

I'm about to start a new project in which I have to make two Android devices exchange data assuming no internet connection. I've seen the Nearby Connections API which seems perfect for my case.

Since the data the devices exchange are private, I would like to understand how Nearby secure the communication. On the [website](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) is written:

> Connections between devices are high-bandwidth, low-latency, and fully encrypted to enable fast, secure data transfers.

No additional information are provided. Does anyone knows how Nearby enforces communication encryption?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When one device requests a connection with another, both devices are given the exact same token and asked to, independently, accept the connection. Users are expected to confirm this token somehow (eg. Show the token on both screens  with a confirmation prompt).

This step is required for every connection request; there's no way to reconnect (yet).